# Is there a "SELF" type in scala that represents the current type?

Tags: inheritance, scala

I'm learning Scala and there is a thing that I can't find out about the language:

Some time ago I was very comfortable programming in Lisaac, and in Lisaac I could write a class `PERSON` with a slot `list:ARRAY[SELF]`, which was equivalent to have `list:ARRAY[PERSON]`, since `SELF` is the type of the object where that slot is.

But by using `SELF`, if I write a second class `STUDENT` that inherits from `PERSON`, then `STUDENT` would inherit that slot changing `SELF` for `STUDENT`, so `STUDENT` would have a list of `STUDENT` instead of `PERSON`.

Can that be done in Scala? I can´t find out anything about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will actually be useful to you, but the closest thing I can think of is `this.type`. E.g:

```
scala> class A { val l: List[this.type] = Nil }  
defined class A

scala> new A().l
res3: List[A] = List()

scala> class B extends A
defined class B

scala> new B().l
res4: List[B] = List()
```

Comment: I don't think "this.type" is what is called for here though.  "this.type" is a singleton type; it is the type of "this" instance only.  Try as you may, the valid element "List[this.type]" can contain is "this".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was trying to remember exactly how it worked.

Answer (score 18):

There is an idiom for this, and it is used extensively in the collections framework (in all the *Like classes, e.g TraversableLike).
You need to add the self-type as a type parameter (like possible in C++ with the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) of the superclass:

```
trait Person[+Self] {
  this: Self => //Declare that any concrete subclass must implement Self; therefore, this can be used with type Self.
  //val list: Array[Self] //Not sure that this will work so easily, for the same reason new T[] does not work in Java.
  val list = Seq[Self]() //No problem here; Array is really special.
}
```

After defining this class, we can try defining subclasses in the interpreter:

```
scala> class Student extends Person[Student]
defined class Student
scala> (new Student).list
res0: Seq[Student] = List() //Note the result type
scala> class Student2 extends Person[Student] //Note the mistake
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Student2 does not conform to Person[Student]'s selftype Person[Student] with Student
       class Student2 extends Person[Student]
```

A mistake which is not prevented is having this definition, where Self is not redefined:

```
scala> class SpecStudent extends Student
defined class SpecStudent
```

Thanks to the `+` in front of `Self`, which makes it a covariant type parameter (I'm not explaining what that is), this however is at least possible:

```
scala> class SpecStudentCorrect extends Student with Person[SpecStudentCorrect]

scala> (new SpecStudentCorrect).list
(new SpecStudentCorrect).list
res1: Seq[SpecStudentCorrect] = List()
```

Comment: Are you sure this more than two-year old question isn't adequately covered by the accepted answer?

Comment: If you read the comments to that answer, you'll agree with me.

Comment: Moreover, why do you assume that I did not check, without even reading the accepted answer? Now, the link you provided does indeed provide a better answer than the accepted one, but I did find the text of your answer confusing. However, the solution I gave is the one most commonly used, also because it is better than the one described in that link: you can't add a self-type annotation like `this: Type =>` when `Type` an abstract type member _of the same class_, but only if it is in an outer class.

Comment: For instance, neither `trait Person { this: Self => type Self }` nor `trait FooBase { type Bar }; trait FooDer extends FooBase { this: Bar => }` work, because `Bar` is not found.

Comment: This is especially useful when u have nesting of multiple types that require these self types.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword in Scala is more or less equivalent.

When developing extensible software it is sometimes handy to declare the type of the value `this` explicitly:

**Explicitly Typed Self References in Scala**
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124

Comment: The `this` keyword does not denote a type.

Comment: > The this keyword in Scala is more or less equivalent.
What did you refer to? If it is not equivalent to Lisaac's SELF (which is a type), then what did you mean? The OP asks for a way to denote a type, since he wants to write something like 'Array[Self]'. And there is a commonly used pattern to achieve that, even if it has limitations (see my answer).

Comment: Surely the link I provided clarifies.

Comment: I had a look at it; looking at it again, I realized that it shows an alternative solution, where `Self` is declared as an abstract member rather than as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The singleton types and ETSR's do not solve the problem. I myself was looking for just the same feature in Scala, but apparently it lacks the so-called self-type annotations.

There are circumstances where such self-type annotations could be very useful. Consider an example (adapted from [Circular type parameters question example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059601/circular-type-parameters-definition-in-scala)):

```
// we want a container that can store elements
trait Container[E <: Element[E]] {
  def elements: Seq[E]
  def add(elem: E): Unit
}

// we want elements be aware of their enclosing container
trait Element[E <: Element[E]] {
  def container: Container[E]
}
```

Let's say you put that into a library. A library consumer should do the following:

```
object PersonContainer extends Container[Person] {
  // actual implementation is not important
  def elements = Nil
  def add(p: Person) = {}
}

class Person extends Element[Person] {             // {1}
  def container = PersonContainer
}
```

It is allright and everything works quite as expected. The only thing that concerns is that a library consumer is *supposed* to use the self-bound type parameter (#1 in the code). But that's not all. Now suppose you have some sort of an ActiveRecord pattern in mind, and you want to add the method `save` to `Element`, which just delegates to it's container's `add` method. Surprisingly, it is not that easy:

```
trait Element[E <: Element[E]] {
  def container: Container[E]
  def save() = container.add(this)   // won't compile
}

found   : Element[E]
required: E
```

Intuitively, we have a few options here:

- make `add` method accept `Element[E]` instead of `E`;
- cast `this` to `Element[E]`.

None of these options are satisfactory, just because of the fact that `E` is not the same as `Element[E]` (implementations are not forced to use self-bound type parameters). The only way I see of solving this problem is to have that self-type concept in Scala (let's suppose we have it in our favorite language):

```
trait Container[E <: Element] {
  def elements: Seq[E]
  def add(elem: E): Unit
}

trait Element {  // the type parameter would be redundant ...
  def save() = container.add(this)  // ... and this would be possible, too, ...
  def container: Container[this]  // ... if only we could do this
}
```

If the compiler could treat `this` (or maybe another keyword), when it is used inside square brackets, as the type of the actual implementation (i.e. the same type as the result of `obj.getClass`), then the problems would disappear.

P.S. May someone consider including this stuff into Scala wishlist? Unfortunately, I don't know, how hard it is to implement such logic since there could be the problems with the notorious JVM's erasure.

P.P.S. Or maybe there is some another Scala-way I'm unaware of?

Comment: You need a self-type annotation in trait Element:
`trait Element[E <: Element[E]] {
this: E =>
...
}`

Once you have that, you can leave out the type bound.