# Circular type parameters definition in scala

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter

I am trying to define a generic container whose elements can return the enclosing container. Something like:

```
abstract class Container[E <: Element] { // compile error
  def contains( e: E ): Boolean
  def addNewElement(): Unit
}

abstract class Element[C <: Container] { // compile error
  def enclosingContainer(): C
}

class MyContainer extends Container[MyElement] {
  private var elements = List[MyElement]()
  override def contains( elem: MyElement ) = elements.contains( elem )
  override def addNewElement() { elements ::= new MyElement(this) }
}

class MyElement( container: MyContainer ) extends Element[MyContainer] {
  override val enclosingContainer = container
}
```

However that snippet does not compile because I should give a type parameter to `Element` in the `abstract class Container[E <: Element]` definition and a type to `Container` in the `abstract class Element[C <: Container]` definition.

I there a way to achieve the behavior I am looking for ? Is there an appropriate declaration for `Container` and `Element`? Should I define a third-party object ?

Comment: Rough guess since I can't open up my compiler at the minute but have you tried `abstract class Element[C <: Container[Element]]` or something of the like?

Comment: Yes, but then `Element` needs a parameter type too...

Comment: Shouldn't `addNewElement()` take an element to add? That is, `addNewElement(e : E)`?

Comment: @Alexey Not in this example. In my real application it takes an instance of another type and wraps it in a new element object correctly initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other solutions already given fail to enforce that the types match: that is, given a type `ContainerImpl extends Container`, you should be sure that `ContainerImpl.E.C` should be `ContainerImpl` and not some other container. Here is one which does enforce this (adapted from http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch13.html):

```
abstract class ContainerWithElement {
  type C <: Container
  type E <: Element

  trait Container {
    self: C =>
    def contains( e: E ): Boolean
    def addNewElement(): Unit
  }

  trait Element {
    self: E =>
    def enclosingContainer(): C
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
abstract class Container[E <: Element[_]] {
  def contains( e: E ): Boolean
  def addNewElement(): Unit
}

abstract class Element[C <: Container[_]] {
  def enclosingContainer(): C
}

class MyContainer extends Container[MyElement] {
  private var elements = List[MyElement]()
  override def contains( elem: MyElement ) = elements.contains( elem )
  override def addNewElement() { elements ::= new MyElement(this) }
}

class MyElement( container: MyContainer ) extends Element[MyContainer] {
  override val enclosingContainer = container
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using type members instead of type parameters would avoid the issue:

```
abstract class Container { // compile error
  type E <: Element
  def contains( e: E ): Boolean
  def addNewElement(): Unit
}

abstract class Element { // compile error
  type C <: Container
  def enclosingContainer(): C
}

class MyContainer extends Container {
  type E = MyElement
  private var elements = List[MyElement]()
  override def contains( elem: MyElement ) = elements.contains( elem )
  override def addNewElement() { elements ::= new MyElement(this) }
}

class MyElement( container: MyContainer ) extends Element {
  type C = MyContainer
  override val enclosingContainer = container
}
```