# How do I create a class hierarchy of typed factory method constructors and access them from Scala using abstract types?

Tags: scala

(Essentially I need some kind of a synthesis of these two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586811/is-there-a-self-type-in-scala-that-represents-the-current-type), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616692/how-can-i-invoke-the-constructor-of-a-scala-abstract-type)), but I'm not smart enough to combine them myself.)

I have a set of JAXB representations in Scala like this:

```
abstract class Representation {
  def marshalToXml(): String = {
    val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass())
    val writer = new StringWriter
    context.createMarshaller.marshal(this, writer)
    writer.toString()
  }
}

class Order extends Representation {
  @BeanProperty
  var name: String = _
  ...
}
class Invoice extends Representation { ... }
```

The problem I have is with my unmarshalling "constructor" methods:

```
def unmarshalFromJson(marshalledData: String): {{My Representation Subclass}} = {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  mapper.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector())
  mapper.readValue(marshalledData, this.getClass())
}

def unmarshalFromXml(marshalledData: String): {{My Representation Subclass}} = {
  val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass())
  val representation = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
    new StringReader(marshalledData)
  ).asInstanceOf[{{Type of My Representation Subclass}}]
  representation // Return the representation
}
```

Specifically, I can't figure out how to attach these unmarshalling methods in a typesafe and DRY way to each of my classes, and then to call them from Scala (and hopefully sometimes by using only abstract type information). In other words, I would like to do this:

```
val newOrder = Order.unmarshalFromJson(someJson)
```

And more ambitiously:

```
class Resource[R <: Representation] {
    getRepresentation(marshalledData: String): R = 
        {{R's Singleton}}.unmarshalFromXml(marshalledData)
}
```

In terms of my particular stumbling blocks:

- I can't figure out whether I should define my `unmarshalFrom*()` constructors once in the `Representation` class, or in a singleton `Representation` object - if the latter, I don't see how I can automatically inherit that down through the class hierarchy of `Order`, `Invoice` etc.
- I can't get `this.type` ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586811/is-there-a-self-type-in-scala-that-represents-the-current-type)) to work as a way of self-typing `unmarshalFromJson()` - I get a compile error `type mismatch; found: ?0 where type ?0 required: Representation.this.type` on the `readValue()` call
- I can't figure out how to use the implicit `Default[A]` pattern ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616692/how-can-i-invoke-the-constructor-of-a-scala-abstract-type)) to work down my Representation class hierarchy to call the singleton unmarshalling constructors using type information only

I know this is a bit of a mammoth question touching on various different (but related) issues - any help gratefully received!

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to not try and attach the method to the class but rather pass it in as a parameter. To indicate the type you are expecting and let the type system handle passing it in. I tried to make the unmarshal invocation something that reads a little DSL like.

```
val order = UnMarshalXml( xml ).toRepresentation[Order]
```

The following is a fully testable code snippet

```
abstract class Representation {
  def marshalToXml(): String = {
      val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(this.getClass)
      val writer = new StringWriter
      context.createMarshaller.marshal(this, writer)
      writer.toString
  }
}

@XmlRootElement
class Order extends Representation {
  @BeanProperty
  var name: String = _
}

case class UnMarshalXml( xml: String ) {
  def toRepresentation[T <: Representation](implicit m:Manifest[T]): T = {
    JAXBContext.newInstance(m.erasure).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
      new StringReader(xml)
    ).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

object test {
  def main( args: Array[String] ) {
    val order = new Order
    order.name = "my order"
    val xml = order.marshalToXml()
    println("marshalled: " + xml )
    val received = UnMarshalXml( xml ).toRepresentation[Order]
    println("received order named: " + received.getName )
  }
}
```

You should see the following output if you run test.main

```
marshalled: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><order><name>my order</name></order>
received name: my order
```

Comment: Thanks Neil - I really like your approach of using case classes in place of my clunky singleton idea. Your example runs fine - but unfortunately I can't get it to work with my second (more difficult) use case: `class Resource[R <: Representation] { getRepresentation(marshalledData: String): R = UnMarshalXml(xml).toRepresentation[R] }`. Running this gives me the error: `No Manifest available for R`. If you have any further ideas please let me know!

Comment: Hi Neil - I figured it out. Posting it below as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated version of Neil's code which I used to support the second use case as well as the first:

```
case class UnmarshalXml(xml: String) {

  def toRepresentation[T <: Representation](implicit m: Manifest[T]): T =
    toRepresentation[T](m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])

  def toRepresentation[T <: Representation](typeT: Class[T]): T =
    JAXBContext.newInstance(typeT).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
      new StringReader(xml)
    ).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

This supports simple examples like so:

```
val order = UnmarshalXml(xml).toRepresentation[Order]
```

But also for abstract type based usage, you can use like this:

```
val order = UnmarshalXml(xml).toRepresentation[T](typeOfT)
```

(Where you have grabbed and stored `typeOfT` using another `implicit Manifest` at the point of declaring `T`.)