# Scala Ordered Mixin Base Class

Tags: scala, base-class, traits

In Scala 2.10.2, I have an abstract base class for a major-minor style version number:

```
abstract class MajorMinorVersion( 
    private [version] val major : Int,
    private [version] val minor : Int
) extends Ordered[MajorMinorVersion] 
{
    override def toString() : String = "%d.%d".format( major, minor )

    def compare( that : MajorMinorVersion ) = that.major == major match
    {
        case false => major - that.major
        case true => minor - that.minor
    }
}
```

Several custom file types I'm reading have a version number in this format:

```
case class FooFileVersion( maj : Int, min : Int ) extends MajorMinorVersion( maj, min )

case class BarFileVersion( maj : Int, min : Int ) extends MajorMinorVersion( maj, min )
```

This works nicely in that:

```
scala> FooFileVersion( 1, 3 ) < FooFileVersion( 1, 4 )
res0: Boolean = true
```

The problem with this approach is that I'd like comparison of `FooFileVersion` and `BarFileVersion` instances to throw an error, because comparing them doesn't make sense, but currently we have:

```
scala> FooFileVersion( 1, 3 ) < BarFileVersion( 1, 4 )
res0: Boolean = true
```

What's the best way to get around this? Is it possible to have the `Ordered` trait mixed in to the base class, or will I need to mix it in to the inheriting classes, and define the `compare` method there? That would be a solution, I guess, but it would be nice to be able to just abstract the comparison away into a base class.

I'm sure there's a relatively simple solution somewhere I'm just missing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrize the type to be ordered:

```
abstract class MajorMinorVersion[V <: MajorMinorVersion[V]](...) extends Ordered[V] {
  ...
  def compare(that: V)
  ...
}

case class FooFileVersion( maj : Int, min : Int ) extends MajorMinorVersion[FooFileVersion]( maj, min )
case class BarFileVersion( maj : Int, min : Int ) extends MajorMinorVersion[BarFileVersion]( maj, min )
```

This way the different implementation classes will be incompatible wrt. ordering.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable idea. Is there a way to avoid having to type parameterize explicitly? Accidentally leaving off the explicit types in the two case class declarations doesn't case compile failure, and the two types are then comparable again...

Comment: You can add `this: V =>` after the opening brace of `MajorMinorVersion` class definition. This will enforce that you specify the correct type parameter in subclasses. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9077750/3080813